# Another Turning Point

Tags: word, rhyme

There's a word representative of impending decisions,
Where you're cutting down choices with careful incisions.
But obscure definitions are not what I'm off'ring—
Instead these descriptions relate to its offspring.

The smallest of these represents the first person.
The next three are bigger. Woman questions: "Insertion?"
Two more, slightly larger: etymogical brothers.
One describes when I lie, one is lain there by others.

'Nother two, longer still: Think of songbirds who've sung
of the efforts they've made making beds for their young.
And of fishermen's dreams as they're casting for prey;
What they did when they toiled on the sea yesterday.

Those all came from within, that's the thing that unites.
But this stanza needs anagrams (this has kept me up nights).
Fill it up, raise your glass! Have a drink on the house!
If your answer's complete it's the one I'll espouse.

{1}{2}{2}{2}{3}{3}{4}{4}{4}{4}{5}{5}{5}

Comment: Is this a riddle? Whether it is or is not, I must say, it is beautifully written :)

Comment: @user477343 It's this: [tag:word]

Comment: Oh, I never realised that could be a tag. I might include it in future riddles :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a word representative of impending decisions,
Where you're cutting down choices with careful incisions.
But obscure definitions are not what I'm off'ring—
Instead these descriptions relate to its offspring.

> Does it relate to **TINES**, like on a fork?
> The title makes me think of Green Day's Good Riddance, the next words being "another fork stuck in the road"
> Having multiple choices in a decision would be like forking paths.

The smallest of these represents the first person.

> **I**

The next three are bigger. Woman questions: "Insertion?"

> **IS IT IN?**

Two more, slightly larger: etymogical brothers.
One describes when I lie, one is lain there by others.

> I **SIT** and one is **SET**

'Nother two, longer still: Think of songbirds who've sung
of the efforts they've made making beds for their young.

> A **NEST** **SITE**

And of fishermen's dreams as they're casting for prey;
What they did when they toiled on the sea yesterday.

> They **SENT** **NETS** out

Those all came from within, that's the thing that unites.

> From within: **INSET**

But this stanza needs anagrams (this has kept me up nights).

> **NITES**?

Fill it up, raise your glass! Have a drink on the house!

> Raise a **STEIN**?

If your answer's complete it's the one I'll espouse.

> That's {1}{2}{2}{2}{3}{3}{4}{4}{5}{5}{5}, so I think I'm missing {4}{4}?

Comment: Look for two {4}'s for birds and two for fishermen.

Comment: @Chowzen Nuts...thought that might be the case.  I added several more words, as I'm not confident in any of them.